# Using PubNub Swift from a custom wrapper class

Tags: pubnub

Everything's great when all of my PubNub code was in a ViewController class or the AppDelegate class, but now for some code modularization and clean-up I wanted to wrap up my PubNub functionality in a class on a separate .Swift file and utilize that.

Below is a sample of my code from a custom Class. An object instantiated of this class is simply constructed with some basic info, can send a message in form of a JSON, and can register a callback (during init) which will be executed when messages are received

There are 2 problems Im hitting with this method:

1. Im unable to see this client when I turn on presence from my Debug
   console in Pubnub, although it can publish, strangely
2. I cannot receive messages and get the callback to run

It's entirely possible that the problem here lies on my Object Oriented programming skills, or lack of it. Help?

```
import Foundation
import PubNub
import SwiftyJSON

public class PubNubWrap: NSObject, PNObjectEventListener {
    /*PubNub Keys*/
    private let myPublishKey = "pub-xxx"
    private let mySubscrbeKey = "sub-xxx"

    /*Object specific properties*/
    private var client: PubNub
    private var configuration: PNConfiguration
    private var pubnubID: String
    private var roomID: String

    /*Callbacks for received messages*/
    var handleHelloMessage: () -> Void

    /*Message styles*/
    private enum PubnubMessageType : String{
        case Hello = "Hello"
    }



    //Publish a message on pubnub
    private func publish(json: NSDictionary) {
        //return an error, success, and keep retrying
        client.publish(json, toChannel: roomID, compressed: false, withCompletion: { (status) -> Void in
            if !status.error {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                //process error and/or retry
            }
        })
    }

    //Receive a message on pubnub
    public func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult!) {
        // Handle new message stored in message.data.message
        if message.data.actualChannel != nil {
            // Message has been received on channel group stored in
            // message.data.subscribedChannel
        }
        else {
            // Message has been received on channel stored in
            // message.data.subscribedChannel
        }
        let json_recv = JSON(message.data.message)
        print(json_recv)
        if json_recv["MessageType"].isExists(){
            let mType  = json_recv["MessageType"].string! as PubnubMessageType.RawValue
            switch mType {
            case "Hello":
                handleHelloMessage()

            default :
                print("How did we get here")
            }
        }
    }


    /*Public Methods*/

    public init(pubnubID:String, room:String, setHelloHandler: () -> Void) {

        self.pubnubID = pubnubID
        self.roomID = room
        self.handleHelloMessage = setHelloHandler
        configuration = PNConfiguration(publishKey: myPublishKey , subscribeKey: mySubscrbeKey)
        configuration.uuid = self.pubnubID
        client = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(configuration)

        super.init()

        client.subscribeToChannelGroups([self.roomID], withPresence: true)
        client.addListener(self)
    }

    public func sendHello() {
        let json = ["MessageType": PubnubMessageType.Hello.rawValue,
            "me": pubnubID]
        publish(json)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're instincts are correct in breaking out interactions with the PubNub SDK into it's own class.  Without seeing how you're using the class, it's difficult to see what the problem is.

In our implementation, we instantiate the class at application startup and keep that single instance connected for the life of the application.